# Why are SQL Server processes still running?

Tags: sql-server

I have a VB.NET windows application that when I debug it, it opens the connection. At that point I can see there are two processes created by going to the Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio. I execute my query and then immediately close the connection. However, when I do that the processes do not go away.

For the life of me I can't figure out why not. This hasn't been a problem except that I have a Restore option within the software that doesn't let me restore because the database is in use due to the processes still being open. They do not go away until I exit the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this is just because ADO.Net actually keeps the connection open so you can use it later. This  is called connection pooling.  Opening and closing connections is an expensive process and connection pooling helps to reduce this cost.

With regards to your restore problem, you can execute SQL to close all open connections on a database.  Don't have access to SQLMS at the moment,  but if you fill in the delete database dialog with the 'close existing connections' option checked and then output the dialog to SQL you will see it.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` boots out all existing connections.

Answer (score 0):

This database is used as a local data store for a desktop app?

Sql Server — even Express Edition — is a *server-class* database engine.  It's intended for use a database shared among several different computers or even applications.  I wouldn't expect a server process to go away just because an individual connection closed and I'm surprised it even needs to start up in the first place — with Sql Server Express these processes are normally already running.

If this database is a local data store for a desktop app, you really should be using an *in-process* engine like Sql Server Compact, Sqlite, or even Access.  The exception where you might want to move up to Sql Server Express for an app like this is when the app you're writing is *the* reason the machine where it runs will exist.

Comment: I think he's talking about spids not sqlserv.exe

Comment: Ah - that makes a lot more sense to me.